# Download images from direct service URL

Tags: android

some URL’s we are having and from those URL’s we have to download images(say 1500 images) and we have to show them in our listview, so how we will be downloading those
Images .(Performance point of view)

Comment: How large are these images? What is the required scope of them? Are they refreshed every time the program is run? Are they cached for next use? Is the user meant to be able to view them themselves or are they just for use in the listview?

Answer (score 0):

Use any Image uploader and pass image url in demo

1) Nostra's [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

2) Fedor's [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList). And;

3) Novoda's [ImageLoader](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader).

Answer (score 0):

See the answer in below link.

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

And see the sample app in github [here](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Answer (score 0):

Use the library [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), it implements exactly you want